# Modal Not displaying properly one shot showing all html content before angularjs loads completly

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular uibModal for popup while editing.I have 4 tabs in modal,By default first tab will be activated and shown.It works fine But when click edit button it render all tabs html then shows first tab..Please help how to fix this,

I tried using ng-cloak .its not working

This is css:

```
<style type="text/css">
        [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
    }       
    </style>
```

And called ng-cloak in html page:

```
<div ng-cloak class="wizard-card" ng-show="currentTab == 1 && renderShow == false">
                        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h4>{{'lable.vChartTitle' | translate}}:</h4>

                                <input type="text" name="charttitle" ng-model="items.chartTitle">

                            </div>

                        </div>
```

This is my code to open modal:

```
$scope.openVmWizard = function (item, idx) {
        $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/vm-wizard-modal.html',
            controller: 'vmWizardModalCtrl',
            backdrop: 'static',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                options: function () {
                    return {
                        "title": "Visual Measurement",
                        "type": "vm",
                        'layout': $scope.stationLayout,
                        'sourceId': $sessionStorage.activeTreeNode.id,
                        'sourceType': $scope.sourceType,
                        'windowOrder': idx,
                        "metrics": $scope.metricLables,
                        "mesId": $scope.mesId,
                        "item": item,
                        "list":$scope.windowList
                    };
                }
            }
        }).result.then(function (status) {
            if (status) {
                $scope.loadData($rootScope.vmStandAloneMode);
            }
        });
    };
```

Please help

Comment: ng-cloak will only hide the uncompiled angularjs code. Looks like your problem is something else. What is edit button doing? Can you post code for that?

Comment: <a title="{{'lable.editCreate' | translate}}"class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-click="openVmWizard(item, $index)" reveal-feature-permission="Allow_Visual_Measurement_Edit"></a>

Comment: This is edit button when i click openup wizard

Comment: I guess I still can't figure out the exact problem. You've mentioned that first  time the modal loads fine and only on click of edit button you see the problem. Is the edit button on the modal itself? can you post code for `vm-wizard-modal.html`? If it's possible for you to create a plunk, that would be much more helpful to understand

Answer (score 0):

The tabs under pop up window are loading all tabs once then activating first this all because of ng-show directive..Which was not deleting before used $scope value...So once i changed to ng-if it working as expected..